# Running Dataflow locally causes JVM crash (OOM)

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Using the `DirectPipelineRunner`, I'd like to run my pipeline locally for debugging purposes. I'm using SDK 1.9.0 with Java 8.

My pipeline reads a table from BigQuery, transforms some fields, and writes back to BigQuery.

Running on GCP, i.e. using the `DataflowPipelineRunner` runner works absolutely fine. However, when I use the `DirectPipelineRunner` is just keeps spitting out the following log info, and does nothing else:

```
19:45:05,470 21866 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner - Executing pipeline using the DirectPipelineRunner.
19:45:18,594 34990 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryServicesImpl - No BigQuery job with job id beam_job_c88ee6741e434aabbf50e73d4e6733d1-extract found.
19:45:27,344 43740 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryServicesImpl - No BigQuery job with job id beam_job_012dca76d75e461480fe75897b5fa7ba-extract found.
19:45:38,150 54546 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryServicesImpl - No BigQuery job with job id beam_job_3548a0ee373a417e8e7570ae90aef78d-extract found.
19:45:47,912 64308 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryServicesImpl - No BigQuery job with job id beam_job_db0b957250ef41279a639bdc113c5493-extract found.
19:45:56,685 73081 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryServicesImpl - No BigQuery job with job id beam_job_3773e0643ec14475aaa140bcf46ea7af-extract found.
19:46:45,958 122354 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryServicesImpl - No BigQuery job with job id beam_job_27af9a1163944cb19e520242de98d899-extract found.
19:46:55,766 132162 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryServicesImpl - No BigQuery job with job id beam_job_5473e6702b3544118c7da8877c900f7a-extract found.
19:47:04,015 140411 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryServicesImpl - No BigQuery job with job id beam_job_40f47d35aa154708a6fc684c8ffb0ba4-extract found.
19:47:11,913 148309 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryServicesImpl - No BigQuery job with job id beam_job_6dce34301c97498884d7344b85a1b07e-extract found.
19:47:35,809 172205 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryServicesImpl - No BigQuery job with job id beam_job_4f7c26d372974095a24ac58b547c13d6-extract found.
19:47:45,136 181532 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryServicesImpl - No BigQuery job with job id beam_job_a7c33e75bfdb41a6990dd66810a0d44a-extract found.
19:47:55,802 192198 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryServicesImpl - No BigQuery job with job id beam_job_a1d7422ca42a4b1d96205bf8c6dada9d-extract found.
```

The log message is coming from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/BigQueryServicesImpl.java#L298):

```
@VisibleForTesting
    public Job getJob(JobReference jobRef, Sleeper sleeper, BackOff backoff)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String jobId = jobRef.getJobId();
      Exception lastException;
      do {
        try {
          return client.jobs().get(jobRef.getProjectId(), jobId).execute();
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
          if (errorExtractor.itemNotFound(e)) {
            LOG.info("No BigQuery job with job id {} found.", jobId);
            return null;
          }....
```

Eventually, the JVM runs out of memory:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
at java.lang.String.toLowerCase(String.java:2647)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:847)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:472)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:781)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseArray(JsonParser.java:648)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:740)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:472)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:781)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseArray(JsonParser.java:648)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:740)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:472)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:781)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:382)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:355)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryTableRowIterator.executeWithBackOff(BigQueryTableRowIterator.java:497)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryTableRowIterator.advance(BigQueryTableRowIterator.java:180)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryServicesImpl$BigQueryJsonReaderImpl.advance(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:555)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$BigQuerySourceBase$BigQueryReader.advance(BigQueryIO.java:1331)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.Read$Bounded$1.evaluateReadHelper(Read.java:180)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.Read$Bounded$1.evaluate(Read.java:168)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.Read$Bounded$1.evaluate(Read.java:164)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.visitTransform(DirectPipelineRunner.java:858)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:221)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:217)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:217)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:103)
```

The table in BigQuery only has 100 rows (it's just for debugging).

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the BigQuery message is a red-herring; the stack trace of the OOM indicates that data is being read directly from the table and not via an export job.

The DirectPipelineRunner is not at all optimized for memory utilization; try using the newer InProcessPipelineRunner.  Additionally, it may be worth using standard Java heap profiling tools to see where the memory is being used.